# Does stateful widgets make sense in a Redux/Flutter app?

Tags: redux, flutter, state

I am studying Redux combining it with Flutter, and I have this question, **does making stateful widgets make sense in Flutter if you follow redux architecture?** I could think that for animations and little widgets it's better to make a stateful widget rather than a new attribute to the real appState, but I am not really sure... I need someone to clarify me this dummy question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redux is not even close to replacing StatefulWidget.

A simple example is animations. Each of them requires to store, dispose and interact with an `AnimationController/Tweens`.

Redux really is for a serializable state. Typically what comes from your API, which you may or may not want to store on the device.

`StatefulWidget` kicks in for everything else.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely. Use stateful widget for rather short-lived UI state and Redux for longer-living state and state managed by business logic.